# Adding a map function to a vector in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a custom vector class that for all intents and purposes acts just like std::vector. I want to add a simple map function:

```
template <class T> class Vector
{
public:
    template<class mapFunction> Vector<typename mapFunction::result_type> map(mapFunction function)
    {
        Vector<mapFunction::result_type> result(_Length);
        for(UINT i = 0; i < _Length; i++)
        {
           result[i] = function(_Data[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
Vector<int> v(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v[i] = i;
auto mappedVector = v.map(function<double(int)>([](int a) { return a * 2.0; }));
```

This works but I'm trying to avoid the need for the cast from a lambda expression to `std::function`. Ideally it would just be `v.map([](int a) { return a * 2.0; }));`
I realize that I could probably write a "make_function" similar to "make_pair" to avoid the need for template parameters, but you'd still need to cast all your lambdas.

I cast it to a `std::function` because I don't know how to extract the return type from a raw lambda type; hence I'm using `std::function::result_type`.

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't -- the compiler just complains that it cannot deduce the template argument for "returnType":

```
template<class mapFunction, class returnType> Vector<returnType> Map2(mapFunction function)
{
    Vector<returnType> result(_Length);
    for(UINT i = 0; i < _Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = function(_Data[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I realize that `std::transform` does this (I could easily replace the body of map with a call to `std::transform`), but my problem is really with the right way to specify the template parameters.

Comment: insted of lambda try to pass a custom functor with "result_type" typedefed inside the class..??

Comment: `decltype(function(declval<T>()))` in place of `mapFunction::result_type`, perhaps?

Comment: There's already a free function with the same functionality in the Standard Library: `std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target), my_function);`

Comment: `_Length` and `_Data` are reserved identifiers in C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, don't use `std::function` for these kinds of problems.

---

I'll first give you an example, and I'll give a brief explanation. Note that I used an `std::vector` to store the data and provide the functionalities as I really don't want to implement the whole `Vector` class myself ;).

[**LIVE WORKING CODE**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2b0b20e2d359187)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//                /---------------------------------------------------------\
//                |                                                    //   |
template<typename T>                                                   //   |
class Vector {                                                         //   |
public:                                                                //   |
    std::vector<T> data;                                               //   |
                                                                       //   |
    template<class mapFunction>                                        //   |
    // Below: use C++11 trailing return type                                |
    auto map(mapFunction function) -> Vector<decltype(function(std::declval<T>()))>
    //                                       |                                   |
    {   //                                   |                                   |
        //                                   \-----------------------------------/
        //                                          |
        //                                          |
        //                 /-----------------------------------\
        //                 |                                   |
        using ReturnType = decltype(function(std::declval<T>()));

        Vector<ReturnType> result;

        auto size = data.size(); 
        result.data.reserve(size);

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
           result.data.push_back(function(data[i]));
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    Vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.data.push_back(i);
    }

    auto newV = v.map([](int i) -> float {
        return (i * 2.0f) + 0.5f;       // Multiply by 2 and add 0.5
    });

    for(auto e : newV.data) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

First, it uses C++11's trailing return type feature. It needs to be done this way because we need to reference the parameter `function`. The `decltype(function(std::declval<T>()))` part is the one who's interesting. In that, we basically ask the compiler

> *"What will be the return type of `function` given an argument value of type `T`?"*

Then the compiler gives the return type and that's what we give to the first parameter of our result `Vector`.

The later parts have the same essence as yours, though I modified them for correctness and elegance.

Please note that in C++14, you could remove the trailing return type and just do

```
template<class mapFunction>
auto map(mapFunction function) {
   using ReturnType = decltype(function(std::declval<T>()));
   Vector<ReturnType> result;

   ...

   return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to not only provide a solution, but also draw all the ASCII art diagram to link the parts together!

Comment: I'm curious about why you mentioned to not use std::function for these types of problem.